# Understanding the prohibition of visiting junctions at certain times in Hinduism

Tags: mahabharata, belief, bhishma

Quoting the words of Bhishma from the Mahabharata:

> At midday, or at midnight, or at night in general, or at the two
> twilights, one should not proceed to spots where four roads meet.
>
> [[Section 104, Anusasana Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b069.htm)

I am intrigued by the reasoning behind this prohibition and would like to explore its significance. Is the avoidance of junctions during these specific times associated with the presence of invisible beings or negative entities? Are there any scriptures that provide detailed explanations for this restriction?

Comment: Similar verse from Manu Smriti -- https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200239.html

Comment: Oh, I think it is due to the presence of negative entities only. @Rickross

Comment: Possibly yes ....